# Passing C++/CLI structure to IronPython PythonFunction

Tags: python, c++-cli, ironpython

I am starting with C++/CLI combined with IronPython :)
I ran into problem with managed structures in Python code.
My structure looks like this

```
[System::Runtime::InteropServices::StructLayout(
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::LayoutKind::Sequential)]
public value struct VersionInfo
{
    [System::Runtime::InteropServices::MarshalAsAttribute(
        System::Runtime::InteropServices::UnmanagedType::U4)]
    DWORD Major;
};
```

Passing this structure to Python is as follows

```
VersionInfo^ vi = gcnew VersionInfo();
vi->Major = 12345;

IronPython::Runtime::PythonFunction^ function = 
    (IronPython::Runtime::PythonFunction^)
        m_PluginScope->GetVariable("GetGlobalInfo");

array<VersionInfo^>^ args = gcnew array<VersionInfo^>(1)
{
    vi
};

auto result = m_Engine->Operations->Invoke(function, args);
```

And finally, the Python code:

```
def GetGlobalInfo(info):
    info.Major = 55
    return info.Major
```

The return value in *result* is *not* 55 as expected, but 12345.
Can anybody please help me to find out, why the value is not changed from Python code?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but:

```
public value struct VersionInfo
```

vs

```
VersionInfo^ vi
array<VersionInfo^>^
```

These two things are in conflict: `value struct` in C++/CLI defines a value type, not a reference type, so you don't want to use the `^` on it. It is *legal* to define a variable like that in C++/CLI, but it's very non-standard, and you can't even have a variable like that in C#.

Try it without the `^`, and see what your result is. Be careful, though, because now inserting `vi` into the array will make a duplicate of `vi`, which would get modified independently.

Alternatively, you could change `VersionInfo` to be `public ref class`, and then the rest of your code is correct & standard.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced _value_ with _ref_ in structure definition and it's working now.